azure storage account list blobs without read permission
I have a use case where I need to grant access to a contractor that allows them to browse storage containers and blobs... ie list the blobs and the metadata....but not have access to download / edit them.
looks like list blobs and read blobs are both granted via Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/read DataAction permission
the list action is defined by a sub operation of Blob.List but the read action is NOT Blob.List
seems like there should be a way with "conditions" in IAM to grant storage blob data reader to my contractor, but provide a condition that either:
A) only allows the sub operation of Blob.List
or
B) only allows Not "Not Blob.List" (which wrecks my brain because of the yoda logic)
when I go to create a condition in the Add role assignment condition screen, I can add the following condition:

but when you look at the code editor, I see this:

which, due to the leading negation, reads like it's doing the exact opposite of what I need.
I tried a number of things and had no success, till I just remove the ! in the code, which gives me the exact behavior I want, but seems to break the UI:

leads to


Have you tried manually in portal without code based?

The user needs to list only blobs and metadata. but they don't need to read the blobs?


use case where I need to grant access to a contractor that allows them to browse storage containers and blobs... ie list the blobs and the metadata....but not have access to download / edit them.

According to this MS-Document,

In Storage Blob Data Reader role Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/read is used which is used for both listing the blobs and reading contents of a blob.
Either it will read only blobs, or it will read blobs and list the blobs.
So there is no possible to list the blob only using roles.

If you need to list only blobs is the way shared access signature and while generating sas, you can set sp=l which only list the blobs.
you can generate the sas token from portal.
Portal:

Now, I can able to list the blobs using that sas token using below request.
Request:
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list&<SAS token>


Now, If I try to read or download particular blob, I will get error:


you say "So there is no possible to list the blob only using roles." but I seem to have gotten it working albeit in a very confusing way

Can you post that as an answer so community will understand.

@Jason please post that as answer so community will understand that way.
